# How to preventDefault on modal links only

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to modify this script.  As it stands it blocks all links on my page apart from the modal window links.  I've tried to modify the script using 
`a [name=modal]` for example to limit the script to the modal links, however for some reason this doesn't appear to work. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
$.fn.modal = function(){
var th = $(this);
    $('button, a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).attr("href") == ('#'+th.attr('id')) ){
            th.toggle();
        }
    });       
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  What was required was more finely focused css links i.e. working script now looks like this:

```
$.fn.modal = function(){
var th = $(this);
    $('button, .report_menu a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).attr("href") == ('#'+th.attr('id')) ){
            th.toggle();
        }
    });
};
```